# How to use nuget in Angular 8

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, nuget, tfsbuild

I am working on Angular 8 project which speaks with Asp.NET Webapi built on .NET framework 7.1. Two different apps and two different url under same org domain.

There is a recent changes in my organization that I must have few dlls from Nuget (Organization Artifactory) in my Angular project to enable authentication. Same I have done in .NET framework - ASP.NET Webapi. Its fairly easy to use Manage nuget option in reference and include those dlls in ASP.NET project.

How can I do the same in Angular project? In my visual studio code after enabling Nuget package manager extension, if I try to add any dlls it asks me .csproj. But I dont have any.csproj for my angular project. Is there any other way to use nuget in angular and get dlls?

Even if there is option to add dlls dynamically during tfs azure build pipeline task, I am good. At no cost I am not allowed to manually download dlls and add into Angular. Because its prohibited as per my org policy. All should come via pacakge.config/nuget.

Comment: I dont understand why you need to use DLLs in angular project. As far as I know you cant use directly dll in angular

Comment: Authentication. Its org centralized. All apps must use those dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not use dll's. Angular is JavaScript framework. If you want to use Authorization in your application, then you need to have a token in back and front sides.
[There is a great article about ASP.NET Core Authentication with JWT and Angular](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/)